# Credit Cards with PayPal REST API

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

My client uses the PayPal NVP API for processing both PayPal and credit cards payments.  That appears to be deprecated or PayPal is encouraging upgrading to REST.  I convinced my client to do the upgrade and while implementing it I noticed the following:

> Important: The use of the PayPal REST /payments APIs to accept credit
>   card payments is restricted. Instead, you can accept credit card
>   payments with Braintree Direct.

That puts a serious wrench in my work.

A little more searching around and I find this option for accepting credit card payments with the REST API:

> Guest payments with a credit card that is stored in the PayPal vault

This would imply to me that the Vault must be used on conjunction with guest payments.  Can anyone confirm if that is the case?

It looks like to enable guest checkout payments "PayPal Account Optional" must be turned on which I have confirmed is on in my sandbox account.

The presumption I am now going on is credit card payments with the REST API will work as long as this option is on in the merchant's account, however, I don't find this clearly stated anywhere and I don't want to continue on swapping out APIs for my client if credit card payments via REST won't work now or at some point in the future.  I also find it odd I don't find any example API calls in the Payments API using a credit card.  I had to figure that one out on my own with a little help from Google.

I appreciate anyone's experience using the REST Payments API to process credit card payments given it's stated that it's "restricted".

Comment: I have found, finding help with the paypal rest and php sdk to be ... slim to none. If you do find an answer (or someone posts) it would be very beneficial. This whole 'braintree' junk is new, and we may be facing this very issue later down the line as well if switching from authorize.net.